Flutter and Aandroid Studio build error, how can i solve this?
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\Raphael Kenaz\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\Raphael Kenaz.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\Raphael Kenaz.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

I got this error when i tried to build an app with Firebase and Flutter... I'm with this problem for like, 3 days and i can't solve it. My java is the JDK 17, but i already tried with another versions, like 21, 23 and 11
I tried to upgrade flutter, JDK, use another JDK, upgrade ANDROID SDK, install the command-lines, change the emulator, tried to emulate it on my phone, i formatted my pc and nothing worked.

Hello, did you try to update the Android Gradle Plugin to the latest version into your project? Which version is project using?

@rolandl Hello bro, thank you for answering. I'm using the 8.3 version

Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79127027/4373661
